# Went Through a Deployment Railscast Trying to Access Log Easy in Difficulty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I spent hours on this railscast, http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps and this tutorial, https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha(which is based on the railscast)

I successfully deployed my rails application to a vps. However things are not working properly I am trying to access my appliation log, in heroku is simply heroku log but where can I find this in my digital ocean vps? also heroku has specific instruction in storing pictures up in s3 do I need to configure the vps to talk to amazon s3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tail your production log at log/development.log

There are many tutorials via the Googles to answer your second question. Please attempt these before asking on SO.

Comment: is there a shortcut to print out the production log? I am just opening it with vim.

Comment: tail -f log/production.log